# Defining a struct within a class (doubly linked list) using a template

Tags: c++, class, struct, doubly-linked-list

I have implemented each of the methods for this class but I am struggling with this last error. I was given instructions to define the Node struct within the private section of the class linkedlist. I get errors such as:

"error: Node is not a class template"

and

"error: non-template type 'Node' used as a template"

My code works if I rearrange things and place the Node struct outside of the class altogether, but that is not really the solution I am looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef int element_type;

template<class element_type>
class linkedlist
{
private:

    struct Node<element_type>{
        Node<element_type>* next;
        Node<element_type>* prev;
        element_type data;
    };
    Node<element_type>* head;
    Node<element_type>* tail;
    unsigned int size;

public:

    linkedlist();
    ~linkedlist();
    void push_back(const element_type& z);
    void push_front(const element_type& z); //add front
    void print() const;

    // will initialize list with n nodes
    explicit linkedlist(unsigned int n);
};
```

Comment: Just remove all those `<element_type>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TL;DR version is to drop the template syntax on `Node`:

```
struct Node{
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    element_type data;
};
Node* head;
Node* tail;
```

Because `Node` is defined inside the class template, it can already access the type `element_type`.  The compiler error is just telling you that you can't use template syntax when declaring a structure which is not itself a template.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove template parameter from struct Node.

```
struct Node {
    Node * next;
    Node * prev;
    element_type data;
};
Node * head;
Node * tail;
unsigned int size;
```